# CakePHP Show different View if user is not logged in

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code in my home_controller:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Home';

    var $uses = array();

    function index ()
    {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Welcome to CreatHive');
    }

}

?>
```

Unlike normal authentication whereby you would redirect the user to a login form if they try and access certain actions or controllers I just want to show a different view for my index method on my homecontroller. So if the user is NOT logged in then show `splash.ctp` and if they are logged in then show `index.ctp`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Welcome to CreatHive');
    if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->render('splash');
    }
}
```